# Javascript+iframe: How to set parent element HTMLTableElement from iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am using this code to get the parent object-

```
alert(parent.document.getElementById('test:input'))
```

By doing this I am getting this

```
[object HTMLTableElement]
```

but whenever I am trying to access it's value it's saying `undefined`.

```
parent.document.getElementById('test:input').value
```

And setting the value also not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `table` elements don't have a `value`. They have child elements (accessible via the `children` [modern browsers] or `childNodes` properties [`childNodes` will also include non-Element children like text nodes), but no `value`. `value` is for `input` and `select` elements.

You can use [the DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) to access and update the table's content. For instance, this will add a row to the end of the first `tbody` in it, if the table exists and has a tbody:

```
var table = parent.document.getElementById('test:input'),
    tbody = table && table.querySelector("tbody");
if (tbody) {
    tbody.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
        "<tr><td>Hi there</td></tr>"
    );
}
```

If you want to *completely* replace its content, you can assign to `innerHTML`:

```
parent.document.getElementById('test:input').innerHTML =
   "<tbody><tr><td>Hi there</td></tr></tbody>";
```

Comment: Then how to access their child element ?

Comment: @AnuragChakraborty: Use the DOM, Luke! :-) (Or if you like, any of the several DOM-wrapper libraries like jQuery.)